# How to pass live data with Intent

Tags: android, android-livedata

How do you pass LiveData with intent to another Activity?

I'm trying to pass the LiveData object into a new Activity that uses ViewPager 2 to display one object at a time.

Here is Live data in the ViewModel

```
private LiveData<List<WrestlersEntity>> mWrestlersList;

public LiveData<List<WrestlersEntity>> getWrestlersList() {
return mWrestlersList;
}
```

Fragment passing live data.

```
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(wrestler -> {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("Value", (Serializable)mViewModel.getWrestlersList());


Intent addEditIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddEditWrestlerActivity.class);
    addEditIntent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivityForResult(addEditIntent);
```

Pager Activity

```
    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    List<WrestlersEntity> wrestler (List<WrestlersEntity>)bundle.getSerializable("Value");
```

I get the following error.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable
```

If you can't cast live data as Serializable what are my other options to pass a LiveData> to a new activity.

here is a link to the git if you want to look at the full code.

https://github.com/Shawn-Nichol/Wrestlers

Comment: Make a copy of the things inside the LiveData, put that in a Bundle, and pass that in the intent.

Comment: @MichaelKrause, can you give me an example? I thought I did that in my fragment already.

Comment: @MichaelKrause Why did you delete your answer, I was just trying it out?

Comment: Your getWrestlersList() returns a LiveData, but what you want to pass to the bundle is the List<WrestlersEntitye> inside of the LiveData and it isn't evident from the code you've posted so far how to get that.  I'm happy to undelete when I can accurately answer your question.

Comment: I can include the GIT if that would be helpful

Comment: I undeleted my answer - I think you just need to call getValue() on your LiveData object to get the List<WrestlersEntity> to pass to the Bundle.  You don't want to pass the LiveData directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getWrestlersList()` method returns a LiveData wrapping your `List<WrestlersEntity>`.  What you want to pass to your Bundle is the `List<WrestlersEntity>` directly, but wrapped in a Serialized implementation of List.  That's why the code below wraps the value of your LiveData in an ArrayList.

So, you can do this instead:

```
bundle.putSerializable("Value", new ArrayList<>(mViewModel.getWrestlersList().getValue()));
```

And this to read it back from the Bundle:

```
List<WrestlersEntity> wrestlers = (List<WrestlersEntity>)bundle.getSerializable("Value");
```

Comment: I'm getting, "Wrong Second argument Type"required: 'java.io.Serializable' should my Live data be mutable?

Comment: Updated my answer - you do need to wrap your list in an ArrayList.  Can you try again?

Comment: I get the following error when I attach the bundle to the Intent

" java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value com.example.wrestlers.Data.WrestlersEntity@bc3ce87"

Comment: Here is a link to the github. I put TODO: tags to indicate the problem spots.
https://github.com/Shawn-Nichol/Wrestlers

Comment: Ok.  So it's an androidx Room entity.  What happens if you make WrestlersEntity Serializable (implements Serializable)?  That should make it work, I think.

Comment: The ViewModel, Fragment, and Activity Implements Serializable.

Comment: Sure - but it doesn't look like your WrestlersEntity class implements Serializable.

Comment: Your right it doesn't, I thought I was supposed implement Serialize on the Fragment and Activity. I'll try it out in a bit.

Comment: Makes sense that you would need to implement serialize on the class the object is created in. Thanks for all your help @Michael Krause